# Material UI table's column width not changing as desired

Tags: reactjs, uitableview

Whenever I try giving width to the column in header row, the header shifts to next row. Like first they are in single row. and when I give width, the column shifts to next row along with other columns after it.

I wanted to get 5-6 columns with different widths.

This is my code for the table:

```xml
<TableContainer component={Paper} className="table-container">
        <Table className="table">
          <TableHead className="table-head">
            <TableRow className="header-row">
              <span className="table-header-span">
                <TableCell className="table-header first-col">
                  Product Name
                </TableCell>
              </span>
              <span className="table-header-span">
                <TableCell className="table-header second-col">Price</TableCell>
              </span>
              <span className="table-header-span">
                <TableCell className="table-header second-col">
                  Quantity
                </TableCell>
              </span>
              <span className="table-header-span">
                <TableCell className="table-header">Total</TableCell>
              </span>
              <span className="table-header-span">
                <TableCell className="table-header">
                  Sold By
                </TableCell>
              </span>
              <span className="table-header-span">
                <TableCell className="table-header">
                  Modify Sales
                </TableCell>
              </span>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody></TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
.table-container{
    margin-top: 5px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.table{
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.table-head{
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.header-row{
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.table-header{
    padding: 5px 10px !important;
    font-family: var(--headingsfonts) !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: white !important; 
    background-color: blue !important;
}

.first-col{
    width: 30%;
}

.second-col{
    width: 10%;
}
```